# SQLyog alternative

Tags: mysql

Do you know any app similar to [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) (sql gui admin tool)? Especially, I am looking for opinion from users who had used SQLyog and found "something better".

Answer (score 4):

I found something better eventually. It is [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/).

Answer (score 1):

We use [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.com/) - Got this as part of [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) stack

Answer (score 1):

I like [SequelPro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) very much. (Mac only).

> Sequel Pro is a fast, easy-to-use Mac database management application for working with MySQL databases. It gives you direct access to your MySQL databases on local and remote servers. Whether you are a Mac Web Developer, Programmer or Software Developer your workflow will be streamlined with a native Mac OS X application!

Answer (score 0):

navicat premium, i think it should be solution for you.
Also,there are free version of navicat .

Comment: From first experiences it seems like this Navicat will be a good move for me. It looks faster and much less cumbersome then SQLyog. Maybe I don't see some negative details which will bring me back to SQLyog, but for now I will definitely give Navicat a try.

Comment: I think there isn't any "free" version of navicat, only 30 days trial.

Comment: Navicat is a famous software. Often considered 'the best' of it's kind. If it wasn't for the price, US $ 249.00, probably everyone would be using it. **So, only for DB professionals**.